# My asp.net core app is not writing stdout logs when error occurs

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, logging

I am getting error HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error when I try to run an asp.net core application on my server.
To debug this I enabled stdout log files as per this article
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/troubleshoot-azure-iis?view=aspnetcore-3.0#aspnet-core-module-stdout-log-iis

But it is not writing any log in the logs folder
It is empty
Why?

Comment: 1) Use failed request tracing to confirm the source of that 500 error. 2) Use a tool like Process Monitor to see if the process cannot create that file in the folder you configured.

Comment: Could you share the detailed error message snapshot? when you get the 500 error. code sample which causes this error. did you check the iis log for the sub status code?

Comment: HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error
The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred.

how to find sub status code

Comment: @jalpa I cannot share the complete page error because of comments character limitation. Is there a way to upload a screenshot?

Comment: ye you can upload images in your post.

Comment: also please add which code cause this issue.

Comment: to find the iis sub status code look at the iis logs which is located at %SystemDrive%\inetpub\logs\LogFiles. open iis->select your site and click on advance setting check your site id. The naming pattern for the folders the logs are in is W3SVC1, W3SVC2, etc. The number at the end of the folder name corresponds to the site ID mentioned in step No. 2. Thus, W3SVC2 corresponds to site ID 2.

Answer (score 1):

Set stdoutlogEnabled to true and stdoutLogFile to \?\%home%\LogFiles\stdout like below:

If the LogFiles folder is not present Stdoutlog is not written so please create it explicitly.

Set environment variables ASPNETCORE_DETAILEDERRORS = 1 in to see more information around the http 500.0 error and debug it.